# Android - this in database(this) not working inside handler

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to enter my database every 30 seconds, that is why I open it in

```
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){h.postDelayed(this, delay0);
                }
            }, delay0)
```

}

But I need to change the this in the expression (cannot be applied to Runnable) and right now I don't know how to solve that.

```
database db = new database(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
database db = new database(this);
```

to

```
database db = new database(YourActivity.this);
```

This is because, **this** is referencing the Handler object.